# How to update content in Row after selection in dojo datagrid

Tags: datagrid, dojo, selection

I have created one dojo datagrid. Every column has a formatter attached to it. When grid is generated the formatter is called. Now I want it so that if a user selects any row the formatter will be called and some strings should be attached to the selected row's column element.

Like grid is like this :

```
COLUMN
-------
a

b

c
```

and now user selects the 2nd row, the grid should change to :

```
COLUMN
-------
a

b SELECTED

c
```

Currently I implemented it like this :

```
if(this.grid.selection.selectedIndex !== -1){
  retrun value + "SELECTED";
}else{
 return value;
}
```

Can you please suggest a some good way of doing this? Please note that "SELECTED" string should not be added to the grid store.

Answer (score 0):

The formatted is not hooked into clicking / selection of rows. It is solely performed when the contents (value) of a cell is set. Instead you'd want to move focus over to onRowClicked - an event on the grid component. It works like this:

```
grid.onRowClick = onRowClickHandler;
```

I wouldnt know which of following samples would put you closest to your goal but  onRowClickHandler could be setup as such:

```
function onRowClickHandler(evt) {
    var rows = this.selection.getSelected();
    // perform cell rendering here
    dojo.forEach(rows, function(row) {
       // this row is an item though.. you will have row._O as its index
    });
}
```

OR

```
function onRowClickHandler(e) {
   var cellClicked = this.focus.cell
   cellClicked.formatter();
}
```

However you may find that there are not much references to the viewable data anywhere in the grid component.. You could use following query selectors to find cell data and update the viewed html by calling formatter on each value. You would need to capture a previous selection for 'teardown' of your custom setting of values though.

```
var prevSelectedRows = [];
function onRowClickHandler(evt) {
    var idx = this.selection.selectedIndex,
        rawRow = dojo.query(".dojoxGridRow:nth-child("+(idx+1)+")", this.domNode)[0],
        self = this;

    // perform resetting of viewable values
    dojo.forEach(prevSelectedRows, function(raw) {
      dojo.query('.dojoxGridCell', raw).forEach(function(cellDOM, i) {
        cellDOM.innerHTML = cellDOM.innerHTML.replace("SELECTED", "");
      });

    });
    prevSelectedRows = []; // reset prev selection
    // look into grid.view.content for methods on this
    // perform setting of viewable values (SELECTED)
    dojo.query('.dojoxGridCell', rawRow).forEach(function(cellDOM, i) {
        // this function might be of interest, lets see how it looks in console
        console.log(self.layout.cells[i].formatter);
        cellDOM.innerHTML = cellDOM.innerHTML + "SELECTED"
    });

    prevSelectedRows.push(rawRow);
}
```